# Can't find my error in integrating $\sin(1-2x)\cos(1+2x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, reduction-formula

My goal is to integrate $$I = \int \sin(1-2x)\cos(1+2x)\mathrm dx.$$

First, I let $u = -x$ and $\mathrm du=-\mathrm dx,$ and note that $$I = -\int \sin(1+2u) \cos(1-2u)\mathrm du.$$

Next, I try to integrate $I = \int \sin(1-2x)\cos(1+2x)\mathrm dx$ by parts using $u = \sin(1-2x)$ and $\mathrm dv=\cos(1+2x)\mathrm dx,$ which gives $\mathrm du = -2\cos(1-2x)$ and $v=\frac{\sin(1+2x)}{2}$. So, $$I = \frac{\sin(1-2x)\sin(1+2x)}{2} - \int\frac{\sin(1+2x)}{2} (-2\cos(1-2x)) \mathrm dx\\= \frac{\sin(1-2x)\sin(1+2x)}{2} + \int\sin(1+2x)\cos(1-2x)\mathrm dx.$$

But $\int\sin(1+2x)\cos(1-2x)\mathrm dx = -I,$ so $$I= \frac{\sin(1-2x)\sin(1+2x)}{2} - I,$$ and so $$I = \frac{\sin(1-2x)\sin(1+2x)}{4} + C.$$

However, symbolab and and wolframalpha give different answers that don't seem to just differ by a constant. I'm having a hard time finding my mistake.

Comment: take the derivative of your final expression

Comment: @SineoftheTime I took the derivative and my answer differed by a constant sin(2)/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "But $\int\sin(1+2x)\cos(1-2x)\mathrm dx = -I$"

NO. What we have is $$\int\sin(1+2u)\cos(1-2u)\mathrm du = -I$$ and it is NOT equal to the previous integral. Actually, we have $$\int\sin(1+2u)\cos(1-2u)\mathrm du =\int\sin(1-2x)\cos(1+2x)\mathrm dx$$

The variables $u$ and $x$ can be interchanged freely for definite integrals, as long as the limits of integration remain the same; i.e.
$$\int_{x=a}^b\sin(1+2x)\cos(1-2x)\mathrm dx=\int_{u=a}^b\sin(1+2u)\cos(1-2u)\mathrm du.$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite follow. Aren't u and x just dummy variables that can both range over all R? So why is it that when I switch dummy variables from u -> x the indefinite integral is no longer equal to -I?

Comment: N, because the final result will be a function of the variable wrt which we integrated. And the integrals are especially not equal because u and x are related in a not-so-special way. Eg. If we have $\int xdx=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$ and we introduce u=tan x so that $\int udu=\frac{u^2}{2}+c=\frac{\tan^2x}{2}+c$. So they are not equal, are they?

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this one I prefer to use the Euler relations $\sin(x) = (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2i$ and $\cos(x) = (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$. They are simple but very efficient.

Applying these to the integrand yields: $$\sin(1+2x)\cos(1-2x)= (\sin(2)-\sin(4x))/2$$

Integration is now straightforward. The result is:
$$I = x\sin(2)/2 +\cos(4x)/8 + C$$

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is about why a certain approach doesn't work.